# Best Approach Architecture of C# Web Application using Interfaces, base classes and custom classes and user interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, web

i am building an application in C# .net 4.0 which interacts with a hardware device from multiple manufacturers and am looking for advice on the best solution to the following

Firstly I have a generic interface IHardware with the properties common to all the different brands of hardware that the application will interact with.

Secondly I have implemented IHardware as a generic class called HardwareController.
Now I currently support three brands of hardware device each of which has additional fields and a different API to interact with the device.

I was going to head down the route of implementing a separate controller class for each brand that inherits the common functionality from the HardwarController class.

What would be the best approach to this?

Following on from this I have a generic Asp.net Hardware User Control which instantiates a HardwareController class on the load event and binds this class to the interface. This is to allow the user modify the properties of the hardware remotely and persist them back to the devices.

I am unsure of how to implement the brand specific User controls, their save behaviors and additional fields while reusing as much as I have from the Generic Hardware controller and user control.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I have to have this item completed within one week.

Thanks
Colm

Comment: It sounds like you need a HardwareControllerFactory.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question really fits SO...

Comment: Hi Chris could you expand on this as I am not very familiar with  factory patterns. I am going off to research that now. thanks

Comment: Hi Walther. Could you suggest where would be more suitable? thanks

Comment: @ColmOConnell, I'd guess Programmers would be a more suitable place for a question like this. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq StackOverflow, at least from what I've heard/seen/think, is more oriented towards actual code. Programmers, on the other hand, focuses more on the programming patterns, architecture decisions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

- Common interface for all devices: IHardware
- Common base class for all that is the same for all brands
- A Brand base class for all that is the same for all devices within the brand, that inherits from the common base class
- A Device class the inherits from the brand base class

Comment: Thanks Shiraz, I implemented your suggestion and it is working quiet well for me. much appreciated.